# NSIndexPath associated with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsindexpath

I have a table view on my master view, and a textField on my detail view. The app is simple. Add a table view cell with some info. Then if you press the cell, it pushes the detail view and shows the cell's `title`/`text` in the text field. In the master view, im using an NSFetchedResultsController. And in the second view, im trying to load the data, but for some reason i am not using my own indexPath variable correctly, because every cell that gets pressed shows the first cells `text` on the detail view. Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Set up the cell...
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
self.path = indexPath;
    //I have tried this as well.
    //self.path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
return cell;
}
```

Detail View:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if (self.context == nil)

{

    self.context = [(FBCDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

}

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

[request setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *array = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

[self setTableArray:array];

FailedBankInfo *infoData = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:self.root.path.row];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", infoData.name];

self.nameField.text = string;

string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", infoData.city];

self.cityField.text = string;

string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", infoData.state];

self.stateField.text = string;

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass the index path into the detail view controller in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, with a custom initializer:

```
- (id)initDetailViewControllerWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

?

I'm not familiar with a "root" property on a UIViewController, what is that? It seems to be an attempt to reference the first view controller from the detail view controller. Have you checked to see what self.root.path.row is returning?

Anyway the path property of your first view controller is independent of what ever cell is selected the way you have your code. It is simply set to the indexPath of the last cell that is loaded. If you did want to some how access this property from your detail view controller, it would have to be set in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, not the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to be accurate.

---

I think that if you set the path in didSelectRowAtIndexPath your way should work. But to write the custom initializer, add a property to your detail view controller called path, and then add a custom initializer to the detail view controller like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.path = indexPath;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and call this from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of the first view controller using

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] andIndexPath:indexPath];
[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(if you're not initializing from a xib, customize which ever initializer that you're using).

Or, instead of passing in the index path, you could pass in an NSDictionary containing the data that you need in the detail view controller (the title and the text).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. By `pass` the `indexPath` into the detail view, how might i go about doing that? I have also tried `self.path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` in the `didSelectRow...` method.  Yes, `root` is the first view controller. And yeah, i `NSLog`-ed the self.root.path.row and it returns `0` no matter what cell is pressed. Okay, this makes a lot of sense. I will try setting the `self.path` variable in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Thank you again!

Comment: +1, and i wish i could use the NSDictionary method, however im using core data and NSFetchedResultsController. But for some reason this damn indexPath insists on returning 0 every time. Is there another method for passing an indexPath between views? (Would this be the problem?) or is it the way its getting initialized? Thank you!